# Kusto Data Ingestion using POST Rest Api call in Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-data-explorer, azure-rest-api, data-ingestion

As part of a POC, I need to ingest data into Kusto table using RestAPI using PowerShell.

I came up with below lines of script after referencing [Kusto Streaming Ingestion Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/rest/streaming-ingest#examples)

However, Script just runs infinitely doing nothing and is never completing. I have to end up closing the PowerShell window and reopen it. How can I correct the below POST REST API call to make it work? Or if I change anything in `$authHeader`, the script is failing with **BadRequest(400)** error.

```
$Collection = Get-AzResource | select ResourceName,ResourceGroupName,ResourceType,Location,ResourceId,Tags | ConvertTo-Json

$accessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://MyKustoClustername.westus2.kusto.windows.net").Token

$authHeader = @{
        'Authorization'='Bearer ' + $accessToken
        'Accept-Encoding'='deflate'
        'Content-Length'='8000'
        'Host'='MyKustoClustername.westus2.kusto.windows.net'
        }

$Uri = -join("https://MyKustoClustername.westus2.kusto.windows.net/v1/rest/ingest/MyDatabasename/VinnyRunBookTest?streamFormat=Json&mappingName=VinnyRunBookTestJsonMapping")
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method POST -Headers $authHeader -Body $TestCollection
```

Comment: What are you doing here?

$Uri = -join("https://MyKustoClustername.westus2.kusto.windows.net/v1/rest/ingest/MyDatabasename/VinnyRunBookTest?streamFormat=Json&mappingName=VinnyRunBookTestJsonMapping")

$uri = "https://MyKustoClustername.westus2.kusto.windows.net/v1/rest/(...)"

Should be enough

Also $Collection = Get-AzResource | select ResourceName,ResourceGroupName,ResourceType,Location,ResourceId,Tags | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
Add depth, as by default it will stop after 2 nests.
Add -Verbose to the Rest call to see if there's something interesting in the call.

Comment: Hello @SebastianWiszowaty, Now, I am getting BadRequest (400) error. Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: Then the $collection that you're passing in might contain some things that are missing or there are too many of them. I'd check what the expected input is and compare against what you have.

Comment: Input and destination table mapping are looing in line.

#.create table VinnyRunBookTest (ResourceName:string, ResourceGroupName:string,ResourceType:string, Location:string, ResourceId:string,Tags:string)

Comment: Sample Input 

Collection = '
[
    {
        "ResourceName":  "PowerShellTestVault",
        "ResourceGroupName":  "Default-Storage-CentralUS",
        "ResourceType":  "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
        "Location":  "centralus",
        "ResourceId":  "/subscriptions/db2578be-71de-4b53-98bf-6f6e5ca2ae23/resourceGroups/Default-Storage-CentralUS/providers/Microsof
t.KeyVault/vaults/PowerShellTestVault",
        "Tags":  {

                 }
    }
]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Kusto does not accepts perfect JSON format. It only accepts the payload in **Unchained Serialized json** format. I am not too sure what is the actual name of this format :)

Below code works.

```html
$accessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://MyKustoClusterName.westus2.kusto.windows.net).Token

$authHeader = @{
        'Content-Type'='application/json'
        'Authorization'='Bearer ' + $accessToken
        'Host'='MyKustoClusterName.westus2.kusto.windows.net'
        }

$Collection = @'
{"ResourceName":"Test1","ResourceGroupName":"Test1","ResourceType":"Test1","Location":"Test1","ResourceId":"Test1","Tags":"Desktop"}
{"ResourceName":"Test2","ResourceGroupName":"Test2","ResourceType":"Test2","Location":"Test2","ResourceId":"Test2","Tags":"Desktop"}
'@
$Collection

$Uri = https://MyKustoClusterName.westus2.kusto.windows.net/v1/rest/ingest/MyDBName/VinnyRunBookTest?streamFormat=json
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method POST -Headers $authHeader -Body $Collection -Verbose
```